# Nginx upstream timed out or upstream prematurely closed on upstream proxy only

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing

I got a problem with the load balancer of nginx. I use nginx as a reverse proxy.

Here my nginx configuration ->

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 400000;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  4042;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;

}



http {

        upstream lb {
        ip_hash;
        server ip1;
        server ip2;
        server ip3;
                }

server {

listen       80 default backlog=10000;
        server_name  myservername.com;

        client_header_timeout 15s;
        client_body_timeout 15s;

   ##########################################


                   #### Proxy without cache ####
                   ####                     ####

                    location / {

               proxy_pass http://ip1;
               #proxy_pass http://lb;

                    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header  Host $host;

...
```

ip1 / ip2 / ip3 are the the webserver lighttpd (with php-cgi...).

When the configuration of nginx is setup on the proxy_pass ip1 or ip2 or ip3 directly, all works without problem (no error, connection fast...)

Now If I use the proxy_pass http : / / lb; , I got a lot of error after only 2 minutes of running (even on the low traffic time) and the connection to the website is very slow (or this page isn't redirecting properly...)

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
```

My question is why with the upstream/load balancing, nginx won't work ?

Comment: Any difference in behavior on the backend servers? What's in the error logs of those servers when they fail ?

Comment: Seem indeed some of the backend servers got error and might be the problem of the reverse proxy nginx.

I add the value max_fails=3 fail_timeout=15s; on the ips of the upstream and for now, so far, so good but I still monitor in case the problem will happen again.